# Axios download file without set responseType

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to get an image from my server without setting any of `responseType: blob` or `responseType: arrayBuffer` or `responseType: 'stream'`,...
Here is what I tried:

```
axios.get('https://xxx/myapi').then(response => {
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/oclet-stream' });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = fileURL;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

`myapi` response is a `stream` that is an image.
But, the `blob` response is not my image (it's something like plain text converted to Blob).
Any solution for that?

Comment: @JaromandaX the response is kind of stream of image

Comment: _"without setting any [...] responseType"_... why? That is explicitly how you do this

Comment: @Phil: we have `axiosUtils` in our project base. We have to use that, and cannot modify it. `axiosUtils` does not allow us to pass `responseType`.

Comment: I have no idea what that is but it seems very unlikely that you would not be able to use `axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })`

Comment: Just I cannot pass `responseType` to `axios`!

Comment: If you're not actually using Axios, please tag your question appropriately and provide details of the HTTP client library or code that you _are_ using

Comment: I using `axios`. But in code base project. I cannot pass `responseType`. Don't you understand?

Comment: No, I do not understand because you have not provided any details explaining why. If you're using Axios, it is quite literally part of the API and also part of the underlying [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Comment: @Phil: I just providing details. Don't you read it carefully? The answer in `duplicate question` always has to set `responseType`. I don't want to set it

Comment: @JaromandaX if I set `responseType: blob`, it works perfectly. I trying to make it work without set that property

Comment: I read very carefully and no, you have not provided details. What is _"axiosUtils"_ and how does it prevent you using web standards? FYI, setting `responseType` is the **only way** to do this with `XMLHttpRequest`. Your only other option is to use `fetch()`

Comment: @Phil: I'm allowed to set that `responseType` property to `axios`. That it. I want to help it work without setting that property.

Comment: Then you aren't using Axios because Axios **does** let you set `responseType`

Comment: @Phil Ok. just I don't want to set that property, and curious how to reach the result without setting it. I cannot open a question about that?.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. If I set `responseType: blob` it works perfectly. I'm trying to make it work without set `responseType`

Comment: _"I don't want to set that property"_... why not? As has been pointed out multiple times now as well as in each answer on the duplicate, that is how you do this. Otherwise, the default is `responseType: text`

Comment: @Phil: don't ask `WHY NOT`, If you don't know the answer! I said `JUST CURIOUS`.  And SO not allow these types of questions?

Comment: Ok, the answer is _"you can't"_. I've added another duplicate link which should help explain why you **must** set `responseType`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. My server setted `content-type`

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't matter what content-type header the server sets in the response. `XMLHttpRequest` does not use it to automatically alter or encode the response type. The default is `text` so that's what it will try and interpret the response as

Comment: @Phil - of course, I keep forgetting axios is just lipstick on XMLHttpRequest :p

Comment: @JaromandaX it's `image/jpeg`

Comment: The server code would still help ... is it sending the image base64 encoded for example? the fact that you mention `plain text` suggests it could be

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. If image is base64 encoded. It works. But I still want to try response as a stream, and catch it from `axios`

Comment: but you said that what you DO get is plain text - unlikely with an image

Comment: Yes. That why I create this question for help. My server HAS TO return a stream (not base64). And my client HAS TO not set `responseType`

Comment: There you go with that _"has to"_ again. I thought you said you were just curious

Comment: @Phil Ok. I am curious if my server `HAS TO` and my client `HAS TO`. Can I reach my result?

Comment: To summarise all this... XHR does not care what your server says. The default response type handling is `text` so even if it responds with binary data, the client-side still interprets it as text which cannot be blob-ified. Here's a quick demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/1Ltcjz4r/. It's similar to the Fetch API in that you must call the appropriate [body decoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods), ie `response.blob()`, `response.arraybuffer()`, `response.text()`, etc.